# Writing an assembler function that calls a power function

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Write a shellcode that calls a function, power().
power() is at 0x8032fc8.
The base is at ebx and power will be at ecx.

I do not understand how to call the power function at 0x8032fc8.

So far I have:

```
push ecx
push ebx
call func_power
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to pass args in registers, you don't need push.  Just `mov ebx, 12` / `mov ecx, 34` or whatever to use that custom calling convention you described.  "passed to a mem location" isn't standard terminology so it's not clear what you mean.  Is that the address of the machine code for the `power` function?  Or is that where you want to store the args, where `func_power` will look for them?

Comment: Thanks Peter. OK, I will try and explain this....

The question is:

"Write a shellcode that calls a function, power()

power() is at 0x8032fc8

The base is at ebx and power will be at ecx"

This is all the info I am given.

Comment: Preferably [edit] your question with the explanation, and leave a comment to let me know once your edit is done.

Comment: Sorry Peter, I am new here. So unsure about editing etc.. I had spaces and returns.. but my reply seem to have put everything into a paragraph! :(

Comment: That's one reason why you [edit] your post, instead of just leaving comments; lack of code formatting.  The other major one is that you want future readers to see a clear post in the first place, and not have to wade through comments.

Comment: Understood, thank you for helping me.

Comment: Oh, this is supposed to be shellcode?  Anyway, the phrasing you quoted is clear that `0x8032fc8` is the code address you're supposed to call (and that's something that makes sense for shellcode), so mov that into a register and `call eax`.  The calling convention for passing args is still unclear, whether `power` looks in those register for args, or whether that's where the values currently are and you  supposed to push them for a stack-args calling convention.  Or mov them to ecx, edx for fastcall?  Or what.

Comment: Yes, sorry i am doing the Intro assembler subject and pretty hard so far. OK, so it says write shellcode.